# java : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java

I am reciving a input in this format 2012-01-13T00:00:00.000-05:00 and which i need to convert this into  yyyyMMdd Format .
I have also set the SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);

This is my coding for parsing the Date

```
public static String getparsedDate(String date) throws Exception {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        String s1 = date;
        String s2 = null;
        Date d;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(s1);
            s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")).format(d);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s2;

    }
```

**But i am getting a Exception at**

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "201201"

```
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Could anybody please let me  know , what might be the issue ?

Comment: The error suggests that you're not getting your data in the format that you think.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the timezone in your format string. If you check the argument, it is finishing with -05:00 and you are also using Lenient==false.

Comment: Thanks for the response , but how can you know what to be passed exactly ?

Comment: I don't understand your question... the input is defined by someone else, I guess, so they should tell you. What the format expects is the first parameter of the constructor. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String, java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the time zone formats available to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) are not ISO8601 compliant. SimpleDateFormat understands time zone strings like "GMT+01:00" or "+0100", the latter according to RFC822. Therefore using SimpleDateFormat does not seem as an option in your case (since you use UTC−05:00 as timezone).

Instead of SimpleDateFormat you need to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output) for that type of date format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: I have edited my answer. I seriously recommend you to take a look at JodaTime API. Check this discussion for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: Thanks , but we were not suppoused to use Third Party API , anyway Thanks once again .